# How to execute python script with multiple arguments and export constant values?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am very novel in the scripting environment, it has to be a foolish question but I couldn't find the answer...

I would like to compile a .py program with several arguments from a github repository. They give some explanations on how to compile it but I don't know how to pass many arguments like this into the command line.

```
export scale=6
export TRAIN_FILE=sample_data/pre/100.txt
export TEST_FILE=sample_data/pre/100.txt
export SOURCE=PATH_TO_REPO
export OUTPUT_PATH=output$scale

python run_train.py \
    --output_dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --model_type=dna \
    --name=triq$scale \
    --config_name=$SOURCE/src/config.json \
    --do_train \
    --train_data_file=$TRAIN_FILE \
    --do_eval \
    --eval_data_file=$TEST_FILE \
    --gradient_accumulation_steps 25 \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 10 \
    --per_gpu_eval_batch_size 6 \
```

I have no idea how could I pass/compile those inputs. Some hints?

Everything would be appreciated!

Comment: The way that is set up doesn't look very good to me at all. The `exports` look unnecessary as it seems unlikely the Python script would look at them via its environment  since it receives everything via command-line parameters anyway. And they should be double-quoted where they are used. You surely have a link to the source of this material, so maybe consider sharing that via [edit].

Answer (score 1):

```
import argparse
def get_inputs():     
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The script is used for extracting cell info from the lib!")
    parser.add_argument('--output_dir',help="This switch is used to fetch the grepped raw data file\n")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
args=get_inputs()


a = '''[WARN] : No sufficient inputs!!!

usage: post_process.py [-h] [--output_dir OUTPUT_PATH] 

The script is used for extracting cell info from the lib!

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --output_dir OUTPUT_PATH 
'''

if args.output_dir  is None:
    print(a)
    exit()
```

to use the path in script:

`rawdata_path=args.output_dir`

You can read more about argparse